# How to build a normal ready to store app with cordova and Sencha

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I have done a sencha app, using `sencha cmd 5.2.x` and    `touch 2.4.1` under windows by following almost all guide lines sencha recommends.
I have already installed android sdk, nodejs, ruby ... all it is working fine.

The problem is that I am not finding a definitive clear method to compile the app for android. At some point in the sencha cmd documentation it is said the

> sencha cmd will only produce a debug version

of the app.

Now I can successfully run:

```
sencha app build production
sencha app build android
sencha app build native
```

and so on. I even generated the debug version (with the last command).

**What should I do to generate a definitive ready for store version ?**

I mean how to use cordova and how do I set up the it in order to compile the whole? I know already how to sign the app. The only point I am missing is the correct way to build a ready to store app.

Comment: in my cordova project (not use touch, but ionic, i think its same) there's build.gradle. just edit that and run using gradle. read [This Post](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#AutoReleaseMode) how to set your gradle

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira the problem is not signing. The problem is the exact operation I should do. How to mix sencha project with a cordova structure, and which cordova command to execute for generating the .apk

Comment: can you run cordova command in your project?

Comment: Yes I can run, but first I need to merge cordova project and sencha project, I am not sure about this,

Comment: create new cordova project, add android platform, copy your sencha project to assets folder. what are you using for native bridge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign your debug apk using **jarsigner**.

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1
-keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

For more info : http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

If you want to do it using **cordova** then create a cordova project. Copy your sencha project to assets folder. Install android platform and required plugins.

Go to cordova\platforms\android. create a fille called **ant.properties** file with the keystore file info as described below:

```
key.store=C:\\Yourkeystore.keystore
key.store.password=keystorepassword
key.alias=youralias
key.alias.password=aliaspassword
```

Go to cordova path and execute:

cordova build android --release

Comment: I have already generated the keys. I will try to make this manual merge as you suggested, even expected a automatic procedure from sencha cmd